# Magento 2 how to split cart data based on product attribute

Tags: magento2, quote

I want to split cart data based on product dropdown attributes.

I want to show multiple cart data data on cart page.

If anyone knows so please help me.

Answer (score 0):

To split cart data based on product dropdown attributes in Magento 2, you will need to create a custom module with a plugin for the cart block class. Here are the steps you can follow:

Step 1: Create a custom module
Create a custom module in your Magento 2 instance by following these steps:

1. Create the module directory in app/code.
2. Create the module registration file in app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/registration.php.
3. Create the module configuration file in app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/etc/module.xml.

Step 2: Create a plugin for the cart block class
In your custom module, create a plugin for the Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart class that will modify the cart items collection based on the selected product attribute. Here are the steps:

1. Create a di.xml file in app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/etc/frontend/ and define the plugin in it.
2. Create a PHP class for the plugin in app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/Plugin/Checkout/Block/Cart.php.
3. In the plugin class, implement the afterGetItems method to modify the cart items collection based on the selected product attribute.

Step 3: Modify the cart template to show multiple cart data
In your custom module, modify the cart template to show multiple cart data sections based on the selected product attribute. Here are the steps:

1. Copy the cart template file from vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/items.phtml to app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/view/frontend/templates/cart/items.phtml.
2. Modify the template to show multiple cart data sections based on the selected product attribute.

That's it! After you have completed these steps, you should be able to split cart data based on product dropdown attributes and show multiple cart data sections on the cart page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.